# wp7 PhoneCallTask result

Tags: windows-phone-7

When PhoneCallTask Show is called, confirmation is alerted.
Now is there a way to know if user clicked "call" or "dont't call" button?

For instance

```
phoneCallTask.Cancel += () => { };
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, PhoneCallTask is a launcher, which means that it shouldn't return anything and the application cannot determine the state at execution. Therefore the answer is no.

Comment: Do you know if there is any workaround? One shat sliped through mind was to poll call history. But this is also not possible :(

Comment: I am not sure if there is one, because the user might not get back to the application at all(phone call task is launcher). If it is really important to you then you can probably create some sort of popup/dialog on your own just to confirm the action.

Comment: there are two options how user may not return. press start button, which can be traced and switching off the phone (which could be tracked also in case user dont remove the battery).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a round about way to do it. You can try it too if you want.

There are two eventhandlers Obscured and Unobscured in the PhoneApplicationFrame, which are triggered when a Shell UI is launched.

Incase the person clicks Call, Both Obscure and Unobscured are triggered two times alternatively. 
And incase the person clicks Dont call, each of them is triggered only once. So keeping a count can detect if the person clicked "Call"

In the constructor of your page add this.

```
(Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
(Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Unobscured += OnUnobscured;
```

Before you call show, initialize a counter and flag

```
diallerState = 1;
isDial = true;  
pct.Show(); //pct = new PhoneCallTask();



void OnObscured(object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
        {
            if (diallerState == 3 && isDial == true)
            {
             //The user Clicked Dialled   
             diallerState = 0;
             isDial=false;
            }
            else
            if(isDial==true) diallerState++; 
}



 void OnUnobscured(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(isDial) diallerState++;
        }
```